# Unable to login to Firebase with Facebook SDK 9.2, Limited mode

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to login with limited mode, but get the error:

```
Bad access token: code 190, bad signature
```

Login in with tracking: .enabled works as expected.

Any ideas on what to do?
Thanks

```
    let config = LoginConfiguration(permissions: [.publicProfile], tracking: .limited)!
    LoginManager().logIn(configuration: config) {            
        switch $0 {
        case .success(_, _, let token):
            let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: token?.tokenString ?? AuthenticationToken.current?.tokenString)
            FirebaseAuthHelper.AuthApp().signIn(with: credential) { (_, error) in
                // Error
            }

        case .cancelled:
        case .failed(let error):
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are using old **Facebook Login** not **Facebook Login for Gaming** ([Facebook Limited Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/limited-login/)) You can check under Products in [Facebook Developer Portal](https://developers.facebook.com/). If your App type is "Gaming services" then you don't have old **Facebook Login** as a product, You need to delete your app and create new one.

Currently Firebase is only validating old **Facebook Login**,There is a feature request for [Unity-sdk](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/826), but it's more related to firebase backend.

Temporary workaround is to configure a generic OIDC provider by upgrading to GCIP. ([OIDC](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/oidc))
And you can use OAuthProvider to sign-in with Firebase Auth SDK.
They have a different billing structure though since it charges a small amount per MAU.